# C# Converting byte array of jpeg file into byte array of pixels (reverse compression algorithm)

Tags: c#, arrays, jpeg

My idea is to open FileStream of a jpeg image and convert it to byte array of pixels without using C# Drawing classes.

To make things clear, i need to know the reverse compression algorithm of jpeg file(so i can manipulate the byte array to byte array of pixels.
thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you want us to google it for you?

Comment: I can find the basic pseudo code algo, but i want to know if anyone ever wrote the algo in c#.